# Copy data from col1 (integer) to col2 (integer[])

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Need to copy values from one column which is of type integer to another column of type integer array. Also integer array column have null values as well. E.g. col1 contains

```
1, 3, 5, 7, null, 8, 2
```

and col2 should contain

```
{1}, {3}, {5}, {7}, {}, {8}, {2}
```

Couldn't create specific script for the task.

Comment: The database being used is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where col1 and col2 are, but to get the data of col1 in the desired format you can do this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN ARRAY[]::int[]
        ELSE ARRAY[col1]
    END
FROM table;
```

If col2 is on the same table and you want to `UPDATE` col2 to those values:

```
UPDATE table
SET col2 = CASE
    WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN ARRAY[]::int[]
    ELSE ARRAY[col1]
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried some more queries and the issue got resolved by using:

'UPDATE table set col1=Array [col2] where col1 is not null;'